# Removing vowels from strings using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I want to make the code I currently have recursive so that it will look at each letter and return this to a empty list. So far I have this and would like to make it recursive. Any help is appreciated.

```
VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")

def vowelRemoval(aString):

    if len(aString) == 0:
        return aString
    newString = ""
    for letter in aString:
        if letter not in VOWELS:
            newString += letter

    print(newString)
```

Comment: To make a recursive function you usually need an edge case where you can directly return a result and a recurring definition where what you return depends on another function call.

The edge case is probably empty string or string with less than one character: what do you return ?

The recurring definition will just compute one character and call the function again to compute the rest of the string.

Comment: I don't think you know what recursive means. There can't be any string inside another string, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to make it so when vowel removal occurs it will go through each individual letter of the string and return it

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to recursively remove vowels from strings:

```
def remove_vowels(s):
    if not s: 
        return s
    elif s[0] in "aeiouAEIOU": 
        return remove_vowels(s[1:]) 
    return s[0] + remove_vowels(s[1:]) 

print(remove_vowels("I have an apple"))
```

Output:

```
hv n ppl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

def rem_vowels(word, new_word=''):
    if word == '':
        return new_word

    if word[0] not in vowels:
        new_word += word[0]

    return rem_vowels(word[1:], new_word)

w = rem_vowels('hello')
```

Comment: Please provide some context and explanation with your answer. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: sorry. this is supposed to be a tail-recursive method for removing vowels. i wrote it as i would have written it in prolog, pretty much

Answer (score 0):

Strings are sequences like lists and tuples.

This is a recursive version, written for clarity, not speed:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiouyAEIOUY'


def vowelRemoval(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ''
    c = '' if s[0] in VOWELS else s[0]
    return c + vowelRemoval(s[1:])

print(vowelRemoval('Hello World!'))
```

#### Out

```
Hll Wrld!
```